# Set of orthogonal transformations that preserve projected norm of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have an orthogonal projection $P:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m<n$ and some vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with projected magnitude $||P x ||^2 =c$.

What subset of orthogonal transformations $U \in O(n)$ would preserve this projected norm? Clearly it contains the transformations on the subspace and it's complement as these commute with $P$ and so $||P x||^2 = ||PU x ||^2 = ||UPx||^2=||Px||^2$. Is this all there is if $x$ can be any element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: As far as I know an orthogonal projection is a matrix $P$ such that $P^2=P=P^T$. How do you define an orthogonal projection $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$? Is it a matrix whose singular values lie in $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Note that $UP$ is not defined for $m<n$, so the argument you present is flawed.

Comment: @Rahul Yes that is what I mean, my notation was poor. Better to say that $P$ is the linear operator $P:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with singular values in {0,1}.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, indeed - it was a product of mixing thought processes. P is a square matrix though is a projection here rather than a transformation so I do not require $PP^T = I$ but rather only $PP^T = P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious what you mean by an orthogonal projection, but I'll assume you mean that $P$ is an orthogonal projection iff $PP^T = I$.

If that's what you mean, then yes: those are the only such elements of $O(n)$.

> **Claim:** Let $P$ be $n \times m$ with $PP^T = I_m$, and let $U$ be an element of $O(n)$.  The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\|PUx\| = \|Px\|$ for all $x$
> 2. $\ker P$ is an invariant subspace of $U$
> 3. $[\ker P]^\perp$ is an invariant subspace of $U$.

It is easy to show that $2$ and $3$ are equivalent.  In fact, these statements are equivalent for **any** operator $U$ for which $UU^T = U^TU$.

$1 \implies 2:$ Suppose for contradiction that $x \in \ker P$ but $Ux \notin \ker P$.  Then $\|PUx\| \neq 0$, but $\|Px\| = 0$, which means that $1$ does not hold.

$2+3 \implies 1:$ Let $x \in \Bbb R^n$ be arbitrary.  Decompose $x$ into $x = x_1 + x_2$ with $x_1 \in \ker P$ and $x_2 \in (\ker P)^\perp$.  Note that $\|Px\| = \|x\|$ for any $x \in (\ker P)^\perp$. We have
$$
\|PUx\| = \|P(Ux_1) + PUx_2\| = \|P(Ux_2)\| = \|Ux_2\| = \|x_2\|.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\|Px\| = \|Px_1 + Px_2\| = \|Px_2\| = \|x_2\|.
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: If your definition is instead requires only that $(PP^T)^2 = PP^T$, the same logic applies and the same conclusion can be reached.

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in statement 1: $||PUx||=||x||$ should be $||PUx||=||Px||$.

Comment: @User71942 that's right, good catch

Comment: is it sufficient that $\|PUx\| =  \|Px\|$ holds for all $x$ in a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^n$? I can't seem to avoid a circular argument.

Comment: Where are you getting that is only holds for a spanning set?

Comment: It is my starting point. I would like to claim that given this, it also holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. This seems like it should follow immediately and yet...

Comment: I thought you were pointing out an issue with the proof. I don't see an obvious proof that your statement should hold. Note that knowing the norm of $Ax$ over a spanning set is not usually enough to determine $A$.

Comment: You should post a new question if you're trying to work through this new problem

Comment: I'll work on it a bit more then post a new question (or edit my question if I sort it out). To be clear I am asking if your original proof holds using a spanning set in statement 1.

Comment: Might help to think in terms of bilinear forms. I'll clarify what I mean by that when I get the chance.

Comment: @User71942 Here's what I was thinking before.  Note that
$$
\|PUx\| = \|Px\| \iff\\
(PUx)^T(PUx) = (Px)^T(Px) \iff\\
x^T(U^TP^TPU)x = x^T(P^TP)x \iff\\
x^T[U^TP^TPU - P^TP]x = 0
$$
So, the question is whether having the last equation above hold for a spanning set is enough to prove that it always holds.  Note that the last equation will hold for all $x$ if and only if the matrix $(U^TP^TPU - P^TP)$ in the middle is skew-symmetric, which in this case means that the matrix is zero.

Comment: @User71942 Also, since we can rewrite
$$
x^TMx = 0 \iff \langle M, xx^T \rangle = 0
$$
where the inner product above is given by $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB)$, it seems clear that the vectors $xx^T$ need to span the set of symmetric matrices.  So no: having the equation hold for a set of $x$ that span $\Bbb R^n$ is not enough.

Comment: I was able to reformulate the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566737/set-of-orthogonal-transformations-that-preserve) into something perhaps more tractable - though I am unsure where to go next.