# Set of orthogonal transformations that preserve projected norm

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559594/set-of-orthogonal-transformations-that-preserve-projected-norm-of-a-vector). Suppose I have an orthogonal projection $P:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for $p_{ii}=p_{jj}=1$ 
 and zeros everywhere else with $i\neq j$. I would like to prove that for an orthogonal transformation $U \in O(n)$ and a spanning set $\{v_k\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\|P_{ij}U v_k\| = \|P_{ij} v_k\|, \;\; \forall\, 1\leq i<j\leq n \iff \|P_{ij}U x\| = \|P_{ij}x\|,\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
In the above post it was suggested by @Omnomnomnom that for a general projection this is not true as the $v_kv_k^T$ will inevitably need to span the space of symmetric matrices on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In this case however the set of orthogonal projections is now much reduced to a finite one which the first condition holds for all.

*Edit*: In regards to the above linked question, statement 1 can be amended to hold for just the standard basis rather than for all $x$.

> **Claim:** Let $P_{ij}$ be as defined above, $U$ be an element of $O(n)$ and $\{e_k\}$ the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\|P_{ij} Ue_k\| = \|P_{ij}e_k\|$ for $e_k\in\{e_k:1\leq k \leq n\} $
> 2. $\ker P_{ij}$ is an invariant subspace of $U$
> 3. $[\ker P_{ij}]^\perp$ is an invariant subspace of $U$.

$1 \implies 2:$ This follows immediately given that if $Ue_{k\in \{i,j\}} \notin [\ker P_{ij}]^\perp$ then statement 1 no longer holds with $\|P_{ij}Ue_{k}\| = \| P_{ij}e_{k}\| = \delta_{ki}+\delta_{kj}$ .

The rest of the proof remains unchanged. It is thus sufficient for the original question to show that the projected norm of a spanning set being invariant under an orthogonal transformation implies the same for the standard basis.

Comment: First of all, in retrospect I'm not sure that I conclusively showed anything.  It is true that $\|PUx\| = \|Px\|$ for all $x$ is equivalent to proving that $U^TP^TPU - P^TP = 0$.  However, given the special form of $M = U^TP^TPU - P^TP$, it might be possible to conclude that $M = 0$ without requiring that $x^TMx = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Second, the assumption that the diagonal entries of $P$ are zero does nothing to change the answer of the problem.  For any matrix $M$, there exists an orthogonal $V$ such that $V^TMV$ has a constant diagonal entry.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that (applying the answer from your other question), $\|PUx\| = \|Px\|$ holds for all $x$ if and only if $UP = PU$ for all $x$; this might be an easier way to think of things.

Comment: It might be useful to note that $P - U^TPU$ must either be zero (in which case our condition holds) or symmetric with trace zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $P$ does not have a constant diagonal - it has two ones placed somewhere on it with the rest of it and the matrix being zeroes.

Comment: I suspect that 
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad U = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}
$$
yields a counterexample

Comment: Using your counterexample yields an $M=P-U^TPU$ that is symmetric and trace zero but without $U$ conserving the projection magnitudes of the standard basis.

Comment: Another example might be in $\mathbb{R}^4$ where the permutation matrix swapping two $2$ dimensional subspaces can yield an $M$ that is symmetric and has trace zero which satisfies our constraints. So $M$ being symmetric or skew symmetric with trace zero is not enough.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I have made a minor edit to the question which relaxes the requirement to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Unclear how much it really helps however.